# Asking personalized, website-specific questions

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering, are website-specific questions appropriate for the Pro Webmasters forum?

By website-specific I mean personalized website questions such as:

- Can you tell me what I need to do to improve my on-page SEO at
  www.example.com
- How exactly can I make example.com integrate responsive design
- Can anyone suggests improvements on the aesthetics of my website at example.com

Or is Webmasters more for generalized advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those would be considered too localized and would be closed. Questions at Pro Webmasters are expected to benefit a wide audience and site specific questions, especially ones that are subjective,  don't meet that criteria.

Comment: OK, that's a fair enough reason thanks. Do you know any StackExchange forum or another forum I could ask such questions by any chance?

Comment: Questions not appropriate for the main website is usually appropriate in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524).

Comment: Note that the main problem with your first item is that the question is *way* too broad. Pointing at an entire page/site and asking how to make it better is expecting other people to do your job. Pick a [reasonably specific](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title), single issue to ask about. (You can ask multiple questions, of course.) You'll also see that in the linked question, it's not really necessary for the question to be about *your* site as long as enough information is provided about what's going on.

Comment: Ah I completely understand what you mean now, Thanks! @Su'